# Uploading Named Binary Tag files(NBT) via PHP - a bit scared security wise

Tags: php, file-handling

I'll cut right to the chase.

I'm building an application that deals with NBT files(named binary tag). They are being uploaded via the usual PHP methods.

I haven't dealt much with uploading files in PHP, even less with NBT files. To be perfectly honest, I'm a bit scared security wise.

What are some sanity checks I can perform to make sure that the file is indeed an NBT file and if it is, could it be possible to contain something I don't want.

You'll have to excuse the vagueness of the NBT part as they're a bit beyond my pay grade.

Comment: A nice wiki entry on NBT files: http://wiki.vg/NBT

Comment: I've read that yes. But I'll be perfectly honest here. I don't have the necessary knowledge to fully understand how they're built. I figured I'd ask around first before blowing a giant hole into security.